# Is there anyway to get private file of user with drive.file scope

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I want to get drive file of user (metadata, content, downloadUrl) not created by my application with access token have only drive.file scope. Can anyone have a solution for this one? Thank you.

```
 gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', () => {
  gapi.auth.setToken({
    access_token: user.services.google.accessToken,
    expires_in: user.services.google.expiresAt,
  });
  gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    fileId: file.id,
    fields: 'webContentLink',
  }).then( test => {
    console.log('test', test);
  })
});
```

Comment: You want to get a drive file which is on your drive, created / owned by you? If not, please explain in more detail.

Comment: Dear @ziganotschka, I have an access token with scope drive.file after user login into my app. Now, I want to get file from drive store of user but drive.files is limited. Can you have solution for this without request more permission?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your issue correctly, but `drive.file` only gives you `Per-file access to files created or opened by the app`, see here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth

Comment: I understand that scope, so I need to find solution to access other file which is not created by my app without request more permission because my client doesn't want request scope restricted.

Comment: In this case, please explain your situation better. Are you using a simple script, a Web App or an Add-on? Is the client trying to access his file on his drive or are you trying to access the client's file (on your drive or on client's drive?)? How is the file created? Can you show a code snippet?

Comment: In my Web app, user call picker and pick a file from drive, after that I get fileID of that file. Then, I send a request to get data of that file (ex: webContentLink) with fileID. Please see my code above.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to have access to user's file in order to obtain the webContentLink

You can incorporate in your script a function that allows the user to share his file with you, something like:

```
drive.permissions.create({
    resource: {
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'reader',
        'emailAddress': 'YOUR EMAIL'
    }, 
        fileId: file.id,
    }
...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not resolve my problem. If I call drive.permissions.create it's throw an error `File not found` because access token with only drive.file scope I can't access to private file of user. I need a solution like make a request to get specific private file of user.

Comment: It is not you, it is the user who needs to give you permission for his file at the moment when he uploads the file. You can implement it e.g. by creating an Apps Script Web App. When the user choses his file, you can request him to press on a submit button, which will redirect him to the URL of the WebApp where he gives the permission to share the chosen file with you.

Comment: I understand, It's mean everytime user pick a private file I will request user to share file with me, right ? Can you explain for detail which API or how to implementation request for share document ? I don't see anything like that through google docs.

Comment: Are you familiar with Apps Script and Apps Script Web App?  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web The  Web App allows you to make your script accessible to anyone to whom you provide the URL. It gives you the option that the user clicking on the link (or being redirected through the browser) runs the script as himself and thus has the authorization to share his file with you.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you. Best Regards.

Comment: Dear @ziganotschka I try it but it’s still need user grant permission drive or drive.readonly scope for app script. Did you have any solution that only request user share file picked and not request more permission to access

Comment: I am afraid that at some stage the user does need to give you more permission. The only workaround is to ask the user to manually share with you the file he picked.